# Simple way to remove escape characters from this JSON date

Tags: java, json, escaping

In my android application, my JSON date is returned as this:

`\/Date(1323752400000)\/`

Is there a simple way to remove the escape characters? (This is being sent from a WCF service to an Android application). I am already using `StringEscapeUtils.unEscapeHtml4` to decode the entire serialized object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the receiving end, if you really want to, you could just do `myJsonString = myJsonString.replaceAll("\\","");`

But do note that those escape characters in no way make the JSON invalid or otherwise semantically different -- the '/' character can be optionally escaped with '\' in JSON.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I was hoping there was a 'proper' way, or a more efficient way..but I guess this will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

actully this not works as it throws   **java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException** instead of using that use

```
  myJsonString=myJsonString.replaceAll("\\\\","");
```

it works fine

Comment: It will just remove all the matched characters, while we wanted to remove just escape characters.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Apache Commons lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi):

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(stringToUnEscape);
```

Class Ref : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

Comment: Thank you! It helped me to get clean html from webview.